# how to move in map of iphone simulator ? dynamic Latitude & Longitude getting but not locate in iphone simulator?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, ios-simulator

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)getGeoCoding:(NSString *)address
{

NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@",address];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:req];

NSError *error;
//NSURLResponse *response;
CLLocationCoordinate2D findlocation;
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSMutableDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:Nil error:&error];

if(error)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    findlocation.latitude=0.0;
    findlocation.longitude =0.0;
}
else
{
    NSArray *results = (NSArray *)responseDictionary[@"results"];
    NSDictionary *firstitem = (NSDictionary *)[results objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",firstitem);
    NSDictionary *geometry = (NSDictionary *)[firstitem valueForKey:@"geometry"];
    NSLog(@"%@",geometry);
    NSDictionary *location = (NSDictionary *)[geometry valueForKey:@"location"];
    NSLog(@"%@",location);
    NSNumber *lat = (NSNumber *)[location valueForKey:@"lat"];
    NSLog(@"%@",lat);
    NSNumber *lng = (NSNumber *)[location valueForKey:@"lng"];
    NSLog(@"%@",lng);
    findlocation.latitude = [lat doubleValue];
    findlocation.longitude = [lng doubleValue];

}
return findlocation;
}
```

i getting location from above code.

```
  -(void)getLocation:(id)sender
  {
NSString *str = self.textView.text;


CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location=[self getGeoCoding:str];

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
self.locationManager.delegate=self;

self.mapView.showsUserLocation =YES;
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 0.3*METERS_PER_MILES, 0.3*METERS_PER_MILES);
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[self.mapView reloadInputViews];
[self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
 }
```

location code is getting after the above function. 
function is called but that do not work in iPhone simulator..?
if the set any setting  Please tell me what the problem in code because iPhone simulator map not move from current location..
Is it Possible? How?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you mean `getGeoCoding` returns a valid `location` but the `setRegion` doesn't move the map to that coordinate?  Put the following NSLog above the setRegion line: `NSLog(@"location=%f,%f; self.mapView=%@", location.latitude, location.longitude, self.mapView);`.  What does that NSLog say when you run the app?  If mapView shows as nil, make sure the IBOutlet is connected.

Comment: thank you. i am solving a error through your support. @Anna